# Finding a substring passing only 2 iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl

I have a curious problem. My fix goes into some high performance library. One of my tasks is to change the interface to use the internal string descriptor format which is a pointer and a length instead of std string for parameters. However one of those functions search and find a pattern within this string and copy the rest of the string after this pattern into a buffer.

I added a change of assigning the entire iterator range into the buffer{ a custom allocator version of std string } and then erasing all characters upto the pattern. The fix was rejected saying that i could do better.

My problem currently is this. My input string is essentially a pair of iterators. I may or may not own the byte pointed to by the end iterator i.e. i cannot dereference it safely.

The pattern

```
std::find(start, end, value);
```

does not allow value to be a string.

```
strstr(start, value);
```

takes a null terminated string. My code has linkage to boost. Is there any boost utilities or stl algorithms which take 2 string iterators and return an iterator pointing to the first byte of a string pattern. of course. there is the brain dead solution of creating a temporary string and then reassigning.

Can i avoid the allocations?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem, but [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) searches for a range within another range.

Comment: just found it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::search(begin, end, pat_begin, pat_end);
```

does the job for me. Please give more suggestions if possible.

Comment: Suggestions concerning what?

Comment: For? I still don't quite understand your problem(s), sorry. There seems to be the one with finding a substring, which can be solved by `std::search`, then there's something about a buffer - why not use `your_string result(std::search(begin, end, pat_begin, pat_end), end, allocator);` where `your_string` is the instantiation of `basic_string` with your custom allocator?

Comment: See [constructor #6 of `basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)